# Toggle display with onclick using collections

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering based on the code below, how I can make a function the best way that I can use on my button to show content on for each element in the class one array if that makes sense? Now when I press it shows content for all the divs and I just want to show for the one in which my button belongs.

I've tried to make a class for buttons and loop through them as well, but I simply don't understand how to do this.

```js
function MyFunction(){
    
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName("one");

    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        
        if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
          } else {
            x[i].style.display = "block";
          }
    }
    
   
};
```

```css
.one{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Testing</h1>
        <div class="one">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        <button onclick="MyFunction()">Show more!</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
        <div class="one">
            <p>Some other text</p>
        </div>
        <button onclick="MyFunction()">Show more!</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes i guess that is the point, i want to handle all div "one"  in some sort of iteration and reach each one some how with array index[?], i want to do something like this in order to not have to do it for every single div that is the same if that make sense? But i dont know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over all the buttons, attach an event listener to each one, and toggle the visibility of the element with the class `'one'` in the parent of the button in the event handler.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.open-btn').forEach(btn =>
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    btn.parentElement.querySelector('.one').classList.toggle('hide');
  })
);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  <div class="one hide">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <button class="open-btn">Show more!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  <div class="one hide">
    <p>Some other text</p>
  </div>
  <button class="open-btn">Show more!</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use event delegation and only attach the event listener to the closest static ancestor. (`document` is used here as an example, but you should choose a closer static ancestor.)

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.open-btn')) {
    e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.one').classList.toggle('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  <div class="one hide">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <button class="open-btn">Show more!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  <div class="one hide">
    <p>Some other text</p>
  </div>
  <button class="open-btn">Show more!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, i dont yet have got the hang of hierarki with parent, child and how you reach them and manipulate them and so on but this worked fine and i know what i should focus on now, thank you very much.

Comment: I have a question in addition to all this. Lets say i have another empty div, and want to add the div "one hide" i just pressed, is the simular but some how .innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap everything in an element¹ and register it to the "click" event. In the example below a `<main>` element is used. When `<nain>` is clicked, the event handler, `toggleDiv` is called.

   ```
   const main = document.querySelector("main");

   main.addEventListener("click", toggleDiv);
   ```
2. The event handler, `toggleDiv`, is designed so that it delegates the "click" event to specific elements and ignores the rest. In the example below, only clicked `<buttons>` will react. See comments in the example for details.
3. This programming paradigm is called [***event delegation***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) wherein a single element² *listens* for a registered event when triggered on itself and/or any element within it. The type of element(s)³ that react to a registered event triggered directly on it can be broad (ex. `div`), specific (ex. `#IdOfElement`), or anything in between (ex. `.classNameOfElements`). The number of such elements is unlimited. Moreover, elements added dynamically at a later time are also included. That means eventListeners are not required for each element when created or existing when the page loads.

> ¹<sup>*Element/Object* can also be `<body>`, `<html>`, `document`, and `window` as well.</sup>

> ²<sup>[*`event.currentTarget`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)</sup>

> ³<sup>[*`event.target`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)</sup>

**Example**

```js
const main = document.querySelector("main");

main.addEventListener("click", toggleDiv);

/**
 * Toggles the element placed before a clicked button.
 * @param {Object} event - Default Event Object. Uses event.target
 * property to determine exactly which element was clickrd by the user.
 */
function toggleDiv(event) {
  // The element the user clicked.
  const clicked = event.target;
  // The element that sits before the clicked element.
  const div = clicked.previousElementSibling;
  // If the clicked element is a <button>...
  if (clicked.matches("button")) {
    // and if the element before the clicked element has display="block"...
    if (div.style.display === "block") {
      // assign it display="none"...
      div.style.display = "none";
      // otherwise...
    } else {
      // assign it display="block".
      div.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  <div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <button>Show more!</button>
  </div>
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  <div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <p>Some other text</p>
    </div>
    <button>Show more!</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. A lot for me to process but i will read and try it out, thank you!

Comment: I have a question in addition to all this. Lets say i have another empty div, and want to add the div "one hide" i just pressed, is the simular but some how .innerHTML?

Comment: Hi, Gips1, I don't  really understand what you're asking. If possible, could you please rephrase your comment or go on and add additional explanation?

Comment: Hi @zer00ne, thank you for the response i will rephrase and give some code examples in another question, i have to read a bit more first, thanks once again though.